# Is removing ~/.rvm/ all I needed to perform a clean re-install

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have installed ruby and gems under ~/.rvm/, now I want to re-install all the stuffs agaain.

Are there any modifications/links live outside of this folder? So, by just removing the folder ~/.rvm/ is okay for me to start over?

Comment: How did you install them: `apt-get install` or from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run

```
rvm implode
```

This is what implode flag does

```
implode    - removes the rvm installation completely.
               This means everything in $rvm_path (~/.rvm || /usr/local/rvm).
               This does not touch your profiles. However, this means that you
           must manually clean up your profiles and remove the lines which source RVM.
```

Remove the line in your .bash_profile which sources rvm installation( i am assuming you are using bash).

Answer (score 0):

it is safe to remove `~/.rvm` if you want start fresh ... but from my experience it's mostly not the problem.

very important is to get proper rvm initialization in rc files, you can make it working with:

```
rvm get head --auto
```